# Right way to handle HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django app I'm trying to deploy. The Apache setting is configured in the way that i access my wsgi app by the following URL:

```
sitename.com/~amartino
```

Meaning I have only a wsgi.py file in my public_html directory.
I access my Django site via URL:

```
sitename.com/~amartino/expofit
```

For that's the way its been set in urls.py.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
('/param_select/$',session_check(param_select)),
('registration/$',registration),
('result_show/(\d+)',session_check(result_show)),
('^expofit/$',media_clean(start)),
('result_pick/$',session_check(result_pick)),
('mail_report/$',session_check(mail_report)),
('notification/$',session_check(notification)),
```

However, the problem I'm getting (which didn't show up in development :) ) is that I'm using a hardcoded HttpResponseRedirect in views.py.

```
...
#If all fields are valid
return HttpResponseRedirect('/expofit/param_select/')
#else reload page
...
```

Since the production environment doesn't place my site in the root of the URL, i'm having errors now because the upper `HttpResponseRedirect` translates to

```
sitename.com/expofit/param_select/
```

which isn't recognized by Apache.

I suppose I could remove the slash and have:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('expofit/param_select/')
```

which would result in:

```
sitename.com/~amartino/expofit/registration/expofit/param_select/
```

but that doesn't seem the right way to do it for I would end up with a huge URL in no time.
Where is the design/configuration flaw here?

Comment: you could use the shortcut `redirect` and let `urls.py` handle the urls https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "the problem I'm getting that I'm using a hardcoded HttpResponseRedirect"

Well, don't do that then. That's why Django provides the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) function, which takes your url name and calculates the proper absolute URL.